# How can I automate closing empty buffers after opening a new file using nvim-tree?

Tags: neovim

When I open `neovim`, an empty buffer is shown with [nvim-tree](https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua) to the right. When I open any file, whether it's with `:e` or `nvim-tree`'s mappings, the empty buffer remains open and a new one is opened with the file.

I want to know if there is a way to close empty buffers after opening a file because it remains there until I close it manually.

I tried using an `autocmd`, but I don't know how to check for empty buffers nor close them.

Edit: I added the following gif to improve the explanation of what happens:

[image: Gif explaining the issue]

Comment: I don't seem to reproduce this issue... Start Vim with an empty buffer using `vim`, then open a file with `:e filename`, then when I quit that buffer with `:q` Vim will exit, not return to the empty buffer... In which situation are you getting back to the empty buffer? Please [edit] the question to be more specific about the sequence of steps that are making the empty buffer an issue.

Comment: @filbranden sorry, I didn't realize that the info about `nvim-tree` could be relevant. One thing to notice though is that what I want is to close that specific initial buffer when the new file is opened.

Comment: I think this should fix it? `let g:nvim_tree_auto_close = 1 "0 by default, closes the tree when it's the last window` see https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua#setup If this works, let me know and I'll turn this into an answer... Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden I actually have that option set in my config and it is unrelated to the issue I have. I think I might not be explaining myself correctly so I added a gif that tries to show the issue.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The gif doesn't show the actual neovim instance for me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, that is my current neovim setup and the gif starts at my prompt with me typing `nvim .`, which opens a neovim instance in the current directory.

Comment: @alexfertel right, I'm not seeing vim show up in the gif. Maybe I'm impatient: does it take a long time to appear?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure what the issue might be. The only thing that the gif shows is my prompt (2 seconds) and vim. Basically, the whole gif is vim and the gif is 20 seconds long.

Comment: It crashes the app on my phone lol. On safari I can’t see more than the prompt the whole time. Oh well. Hope it’s just me.